# How to check who minted a NFT?

Tags: nft, mint

I try to get who perform the mint operation on a NFT. My understanding is that a transaction having a `from_address` which is the genesis address - 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and the `to_address` is the address of the wallet who minted the NFT.

Though I found that some NFT like this one: https://opensea.io/assets/0xc4c377565a4b9eb6e657c2422bd33b6e4859b041/1 doesn't have any mint operation or having any transaction having the `from_address` is the genesis address. I've checked all the transactions downloaded from Etherscan from here: https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=address&a=0xc4c377565a4b9eb6e657c2422bd33b6e4859b041.

So maybe I get incorrect understanding on how the minting process works. Any specification on how minting process work is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace the transaction to the first time this NFT has been transfered and then follow the transaction back the tx that it is minted.
Here is the tx - https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9d74c293a2ef61a1dda4175a6884fe85955335d8c4731ffe0d03d4e6856a593

Comment: Thank you. This is same method I'm thinking of too. 
Following the mentioned method, is it correct to state that there is only one minter per NFT contract - regardless of how many supply per NFT?

Comment: I've just found that the example NFT have been minted multiple times. So there are not only one minter per NFT.

Comment: The example NFT is ERC1155 unlike regular NFT which is ERC721. Essentially, ERC1155 allow multiple owner to 1 NFT